# Why does Socket.Receive throw SocketException (10054) when remote host disconnects?

Tags: c#, .net

I used to write socket programs in C and can't understand why the above is happening.

My server blocks at a Receive call, when it returns 0, I break out of the while loop and shutdown the thread.

```
 public class MyServer {

    public MyServer() {
    }

    public void Init() {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(StartListening);
        while (true) {
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public void StartListening(Object state) {
        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        try {
            // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true) {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                // get connection
                Socket client = listener.Accept();
                // push client to another thread
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(HandleClient, client);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void HandleClient(Object obj) {
        // Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Socket client = (Socket)obj;

        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = client;

        try {
            while (true) {
                int bytesRead = client.Receive(state.buffer);
                Console.WriteLine("bytesRead=" + bytesRead);

                // remote dc.
                if (bytesRead == 0)
                    break;

                String content = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}", content.Length, content);
                client.Send(state.buffer, 0, state.buffer.Length, 0);
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", e.ToString());
        }
        client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        client.Close();
    }


    private void Send(Socket handler, String data) {
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        //handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);

    }
}
```

However, when I click on the close button ("x") of the client, server's Receive call throws a SocketException. According to [MSDN's Remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff.aspx), this shouldn't happen because I've satisfied both the connection-oriented part (see above) and client shutdown part(see below) conditions.

```
Client.cs (pseudo):

public class MyClient {
public void Init() {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    Socket sender = null;
    try {
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
        sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
           SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        sender.Connect(remoteEP);

        Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
            sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

        while (true) {
            // Encode the data string into a byte array.
            String input = Console.ReadLine();
            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);

            // Send the data through the socket.
            int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

            // Receive the response from the remote device.
            int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",
                Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));
        }



    } catch (ArgumentNullException ane) {
        Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
    } catch (SocketException se) {
        Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
    } finally {
        sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        sender.Close();
    }
}
```

}

My shallow understanding of finally blocks is that it will always execute. But it doesn't seem to be the case here.

SO, what did I do wrong here? Should I just catch the exception, close the client socket on the server side and just move on, ignoring it? But I would prefer if an exception were not thrown at all.

Comment: What is the `SocketErrorCode` on the `SocketException`?

Comment: What is the error-code of the exception? Also: the client has an infinite loop: that surely means it never calls the client shutdown? Since the server doesn't send, it is unclear to me what the client is trying to receive...

Comment: 10054, connection reset by peer. The client's cleanup is inside the finally block, wouldn't that execute when I close the client? The server echoes whatever the client sends him, but I left it out to keep it concise.

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed the question to make it clear.

Comment: In my experience, for console applications, clicking the 'x' immediately ends the program. No more code executes, even finally blocks. You should be prepared for the case where the client process is forcefully ended or the network connection is interrupted.

Comment: @mike: If so, the only and correct way would be to catch the exception then?